# process.diagnostic waiting for user input

Tags: c#, multithreading, process, user-input

I have a simple WPF application that communicates with another console program. I use `Process.Diagnostic` to launch the console app. That console app has a prompt so I can send the input through `StandardInput` and read the outcome through `StandardOutput`.
I want to launch the console application only once (keep it alive whole time) when the WPF apps loads and keep sending input and reads the output.

I have some piece of code but I don’t how to put it all together.

The problem is that after sending the input I want to wait until the prompt occurs before I start reading the output line by line so I have entire outcome. I know I can check if the process is waiting for input like that:

```
foreach (ProcessThread thread in _proccess.Threads)
{
    if (thread.ThreadState == System.Diagnostics.ThreadState.Wait
        && thread.WaitReason == ThreadWaitReason.UserRequest)
    {
        _isPrompt = true;
    }
}
```

But where should I put that code to check if the `ThreadState` has changed? In a separate thread and how to do that?

I hope that someone can put some light on that issue.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In a WPF app you can use the [System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Example adapted from MSDN documentation:

```
// code assumes dispatcherTimer, _process and _isPrompt are declared on the WFP form

this.dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
this.dispatcherTimer.Tick += (sender, e) =>
{
    this._isPrompt = proc
        .Threads
        .Cast<ProcessThread>()
        .Any(t => t.WaitReason == ThreadWaitReason.UserRequest);
};
this.dispatcherTimer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
this.dispatcherTimer.Start();

...

this._process.Start();
```