# Using Command line application with my asp.net application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I doing my final year project by implementing learning web application using ASP.NET Core 
however, in some page i need the user to interact with some command line application where these commands need to be sent based on the given output from the command line application. I have no issue with sending on command, but when it comes to the second command i got several issues. here is the code

```
public static Process process = new Process()
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        FileName = "cmd",
        RedirectStandardOutput = true,
        RedirectStandardInput = true,
        UseShellExecute = false,
        CreateNoWindow = true,

        }
    };
```

This is my definition for my process i have created outside the function because i do need to use the same process several time until the user leave the page. 
For the `process.Start();` I have putted with the function of viewing the page, so the process is started already and no issue with it.

```
    public IActionResult acceptingInputFromUser(string input)
    {

        string result;
        try
        {
            StreamWriter sw = process.StandardInput;
            StreamReader rd = process.StandardOutput;


            using (process.StandardInput)
            {

                sw.WriteLine(input);
                sw.Flush();
                sw.Close();
                result = process.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }catch (Exception ex)
        {
             result = ex.ToString();
        }

        return Json(result);

    }
```

**Here where is the issue**, once the user submit any input the the first time will accept and give the result, however when he send another request it says

> Cannot write to a closed TextWriter

I have tried several ways but so far i couldn't find solution. Can anyone help me with this error like how I can open the Textwriter again or if there is any other efficient way to where I can use CMD freely.

Comment: You are disposing of it with the `using(process.StandardInput`). Remove this code.

Comment: I tried, same thing. the mean thing its about closing the StreamWriter, I have to close it in order to read the output other wise I won't be able to read the output and display it

Comment: if this helps, this also same kind of issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29829028/c-sharp-standardoutput-hangs-how-can-i-detect-its-waiting-for-input

Comment: this one also is the same issue https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8978512/process-diagnostic-waiting-for-user-input